# Does this checkers-like game exist

Tags: identify-this-game, checkers

I had a dream where my wife taught me a game she called Serendipity. I woke up and quickly programmed it. I don't believe that anything is invented in dreams, so I'm now searching for the real game that slipped into my dream. I want to know what the proper rules are. I'm tagging this as checkers for now because it is very much like checkers, but a completely different game.

If you want to simply see the game, it is at: http://shaunwagner.com/serendipity
Note: I wrote this very quickly this morning, so expect plenty of bugs.

The game is like checkers. All the chips are the same color (I call them stones to make it obvious this isn't checkers). The board is set up like checkers, but all the stones on both sides are the same color. The goal is to capture 13 stones.

Each turn has 3 steps: (1) Pick a stone and move it diagonally. It can be any stone on the board that can move. It can move in any direction. This is like a "kinged" chip in checkers. (2) Repeat step one, moving another stone. It has to be a different stone. (3) Pick any stone not used in steps 1 and 2 and jump with it. It jumps like a "kinged" chip in checkers. You can multi-jump or chain your jumps. You capture each stone you jump.

If, for any reason, you don't want to or cannot complete a step of your move, you pass to the other player. If both players pass, the game is a draw.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting game.  I don't recognize it, but I can see where it has some depth (maybe more than checkers).

Comment: Interesting concept. ARe you aware, however, that there already exists a board game named «Serendipity» ? BoardGameGeek reference : https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/34655/serendipity

Comment: A game by that name does in fact already exist, unfortunately it doesn't seem to be at all what you are looking for...

Comment: Thanks. I assumed a game like it existed. In my dream, my wife called it Serendipity, so that is the name I used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This strikes me as a modified two player version of [Peg Solitaire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peg_solitaire), rather than checkers.

Notably:

1. Players alternate turns except that a player is granted additional consecutive moves (i.e., captures) during a single turn, under certain circumstances.
2. Players must readjust two separate pegs prior to their first move of a turn, then they must move using a third peg. Consecutive moves must be made with that same peg.

This, of course, changes the win condition from "remove all the pegs, but one" to "mess up your opponents peg-capturing board state, worse than they mess up yours, and whoever gets the most captures, wins"

Best of luck marketing this game as well as the new Pandemic-killer, "fully cooperative peg solitaire," coming soon to your dreams!